# How to set mask/pattern for a phonenumber textbox as xxx-xxx-xxxx in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox for phonenumber and I need to enter the phonenumber in `xxx-xxx-xxxx` format in the textbox.

I have tried below examples but thy are not working

```
<input type='text' ng-model='nerecord.phonenumber' mask='xxx-xxx-xxxx'/>

<input type='text' ng-model='nerecord.phonenumber' ng-pattern='/^[1-10]\d{2}([.-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}$/'/>
```

Can anyone help me. How to do this?

Comment: Try with ui-mask instead of mask.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your regex isn't correct.
try this one  /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything to handle the case your phone number is invalid.

try to render something like that :

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="yourSaveFunction()">
  <p ng-class="{ error: !myForm.phoneNumber.$valid }"> <!-- You must handle your css with this class -->
    <label ng-if="!myForm.phoneNumber.$valid">Phone Number not OK</label>
    <input name="phoneNumber" type='text' ng-model='nerecord.phonenumber' ng-pattern='someRegex'/> <!-- idk anything about regex -->
  </p>
  <p>
     <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't want to  display validation message.        I want something like   Social Security # in the below link.  http://www.bootply.com/EzExkBjBtM

Comment: It's just CSS + javascript. They remove the style to each input, then put a frame on top of it, and they switch between inputs with events

Answer (score 0):

UI Mask example:

```
<input ng-model="nerecord.phonenumber" ui-mask="999-999-9999" type="text"/>
```

Also if you have to validate the input then there is an option in config to prevent clearing the value on blur.

clearOnBlur: false

[Mask.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/blob/master/dist/mask.js)